# TypeAhead not working on Android WebView

Tags: android, angularjs, webview, typeahead

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" typeahead-on-select="setDeliveryArea($item)" ng-model="scope.da" placeholder="Set Delivery Location" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Set Delivery Location'" typeahead="a as a.AreaName for a in scope.deliveryAreas | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" ng-blur="getDelivery()" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-append-to-body="false" autocomplete="off" />
```

Above is the code that I am using to set a textbox to display the list of Autocomplete from the database.

While it is working perfectly fine on all browsers on desktop. Its even working on Mobile View on chrome. However, when the same link/page is opened and control is accessed in an Android WebView, it is not working.

Any suggestions to resolve this ?

PS - `autocomplete="off"` is something which was not earlier but I had put it based on some google searches I did. So irrespective of this tag, its not working.

Similar funcionality on a different page is working fine. The code for that textbox is as below. This perfectly shows the list even in Android WebView.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="area" placeholder="Delivery Area" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Delivery Area'" typeahead="a as a.AreaName for a in areas | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" typeahead-on-select="setDeliveryArea($item)" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-append-to-body="false" ng-blur="area=(area||'')" typeahead-on-select="model=$item.AreaId">
```

Comment: Anyone ? I am still stuck